# Captive Dependency with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I’m looking for the cleanest way to solve the Captive Dependency problem with autofac.

I have a short lived class that will be registerd per LifeTimeScope:

```
public class ShortLived
{
    public void DoSomethingUsefull() {}
}
```

And I have a long living class that will be registered as single instance. It has a dependency on the ShortLived class:

```
public class LongLived
{
    private readonly Func<ShortLived> _getCurrentShortLived;

    public LongLived(Func<ShortLived> getCurrentShortLived)
    {
        _getCurrentShortLived = getCurrentShortLived;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithShortLived()
    {
        var currentShortLived = _getCurrentShortLived();
        currentShortLived.DoSomethingUsefull();
    }
}
```

The following attempt doesn't work. It throws an Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException.

```
public void CaptiveDependencyTest()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<LongLived>()
        .SingleInstance();
    var container = builder.Build();

    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(b => b.RegisterType<ShortLived>()))
    {
        var longLived = scope.Resolve<LongLived>();
        longLived.DoSomethingWithShortLived();
    }
}
```

The following does work. But I realy hope there is a better solution to the problem than relying on a somehow static variable.

```
private static ILifetimeScope currentLifetimeScope;

public void CaptiveDependencyTest2()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Register(c =>
    {
        Func<ShortLived> shortLivedFacotry = () => currentLifetimeScope.Resolve<ShortLived>();
        return new LongLived(shortLivedFacotry);
    })
    .SingleInstance();
    var container = builder.Build();

    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(b => b.RegisterType<ShortLived>()))
    {
        currentLifetimeScope = scope;
        var longLived = scope.Resolve<LongLived>();
        longLived.DoSomethingWithShortLived();
    }
}
```

Some Backround Infos:
I’m working on an OWIN hosted ASP.Net WebApi2 Microservice. When calling other services, I need to read values from the currentOwinContext.Request.User.Identity and add them to the RequestMessage I send to the next service. My LongLived class is a DelegatingHandler (i.e. part of the HttpClient "HttpMessageHandler-Pipeline"), and the HttpClient needs to be .SingleInstance() so I don’t have to instantiate new HttpClients for each request I make. The ShortLived class is IOwinContext, which is registered in a LifeTimeScope in the Owin Pipeline.

Instead of a static variable for the currentLifeTimeScope I could register the HttpConfiguration in autofac. Then I could get the currentLifeTimeScope with httpConfig.DependencyResolver.GetRequestLifetimeScope(); I haven’t tested this approach yet. I still hope to find something cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If type T is registered with the container, Autofac will automatically resolve dependencies on Func as factories that create T instances through the container please find more info about Delegate Factories

Register your ShortLived class as below that's it all's working fine now.

```
public void CaptiveDependencyTest()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<ShortLived>()
        .SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<LongLived>()
        .SingleInstance();
    var container = builder.Build();

    //using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(b => b.RegisterType<ShortLived>()))
    //{
        var longLived = container.Resolve<LongLived>();
        longLived.DoSomethingWithShortLived();
    //}
}
```

and you can directly resolve as well from container using is no longer needed but at the end choice is yours

Comment: You've made the short lived dependency a singleton? I think you're not understanding the concept of a "captive dependency" -- a long lived component holds on to a reference to a short lived component, thereby making that component long lived as well (usually unintentionally). If you make both components singletons, then "captive dependency" does not even apply and you have not addressed the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

In **ASP.NET Core**, the `HttpContext` class provides the property `public IServiceProvider RequestServices { get; set; }`. This can be used to resolve dependencies from the request lifetime scope even if you only have a reference to the root lifetime scope. The trick is to remember that the `ILifetimeScope` can be resolved from any `IComponentContext`. This behavior can be encapsulated in the following extension method.

```
public static ILifetimeScope GetLifetimeScope(this HttpContext httpContext)
{
   return httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ILifetimeScope)) as ILifetimeScope;
}
```

Now you can easily get to the "per request" lifetime scope with the following code, given an instance of `IComponentContext`.

```
ctx => {
  var requestScope = ctx.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.GetLifetimeScope();

  var shortLived = requestScope.Resolve<ShortLived>();
}
```

---

---

In traditional **ASP.NET**, there is a "dependency resolver" instead of a "service provider".

e.g. `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =` *integrate autofac here*

Resolving the `ILifetimeScope` is a little messier.

```
public static ILifetimeScope GetLifetimeScope(this HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var requestMessage = httpContext.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage;

    return requestMessage?.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(ILifetimeScope)) as ILifetimeScope;
}
```

```
var requestScope = HttpContext.Current.GetLifetimeScope();

var shortLived = requestScope.Resolve<ShortLived>();
```